# What is best way for including bootstrap.css to nuxt project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

This is a part of my nuxt.config.js file:

```
 head: {

 link: [
     { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
       // load bootsttrap.css from CDN      
       //{ type: 'text/css', rel: 'stylesheet', href: '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' },
     ]
   },
   css: [
     // this line include bootstrap.css in each html file on generate 
     'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
     'assets/main.css'
   ],
```

In this case bootstrap.css included in each html file on *nuxt generate*.
For resolve it I comment line *'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'* in css section and uncomment *rel stylesheet* line in link section.

After this bootstrap.css file loaded from CDN and not included in html files. So, I think it not is very well idea.

How copy bootstrap.css from 'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/...' to '~/assets' on build, and after this, load it from here?

Answer (score 17):

Steps to include bootstrap.css into a nuxt project:

1 .**Install bootstrap-vue**

```
 npm i bootstrap-vue
```

2.Create the file **plugins/bootstrap-vue.js** and in it type:

```
/* eslint-disable import/first */
import Vue from 'vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

3.Add created plugin to **nuxt.config.js**:

```
 plugins: [
    '@/plugins/bootstrap-vue',
  ],
```

After these steps it should work and you can use bootstrap.

Comment: OP asked about Bootstrap, not Bootstrap-vue. Bootstrap-vue is a memory hog. I have an open issue with it requiring 500K in the final build. I'd love to use it but until they fix that, no go.

Comment: @PeterT Its been quite a long time since your comment, but I have to ask. Have they solved the issue?

Comment: @PeterT thanks for pointing that out.  This answer was provided back in 2019 when integrating regular Bootstrap directly into the project was not so straightforward as nowadays. During that time, I found that using bootstrap-vue as the best available alternative.

Answer (score 14):

This is the simplest way I have found to include the *regular* Bootstrap version (*not* Bootstrap-Vue) in your Nuxt.js project. First, install Bootstrap from your Nuxt.js project directory (I'm using version 5.0.0-beta2):

```
npm install bootstrap
```

Then, in `nuxt.config.js` file, include Bootstrap's CSS and Javascript like this:

```
css: [
    "~/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
plugins: [
    { src: "~/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js", mode: "client" }
],
```

Note the **`mode: "client"`** flag which indicates that the Javascript should only be run on the client. This prevents a `ReferenceError: document is not defined` error that happens because Bootstrap is not compatible with server side rendering.

Answer (score 8):

## For me the best way if you are using scss

As for me i create a `sass` directory inside `assets` directory in nuxt.

Then i add `app.scss` file inside `sass` directory i just created.

Then inside `app.scss` i import the following:

`@import "bootstrap-variable-override";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";`

Then i do `yarn add node-sass sass-loader --save`

After that in `nuxt.config.js` i modify css array to include my ***app.scss***

```
  css: [
    '@/assets/sass/app.scss'
  ],
```

This will compile whatever scss i will write and import in ***app.scss*** and provide as a compiled css.

But if you are bootstrap-vue then all you need to do is add this as modules:

```
  modules: ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt']
```

Comment: @import "bootstrap-variable-override"; threw an error for me. Removed and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 5):

### Way to add Bootstrap 5 with nuxt.js:

> If you don't want to do it manually by reading the following answer, you can simply clone my bootstrap 5 with nuxt boilerplate repository, [click here](https://github.com/Rasaf-Ibrahim/Vue.js-Boilerplates/tree/005).

#### Installation

```
npm install bootstrap@next
```

> Note: The command will change, currently bootstrap 5 is in the beta version.

After installing the bootstrap, you will know that you need to install some loaders to compile Bootstrap.

```
npm install --save-dev sass sass-loader fibers postcss postcss-loader autoprefixer
```

> Note: Installation of fibers is not mentioned in bootstrap documentation but synchronous compilation with sass (2x speed increase) is enabled automatically when fibers is installed.

#### Adding the CSS Part of Bootstrap and the Customized Bootstrap

At first, create a folder in your nuxt project’s **assests** folder and also create a scss file inside the created folder. Suppose, the folder’s name is bootstrap and the file name is ‘mystyle.scss’. Now, on this mystyle.scss file, you can override any built-in custom Bootstrap variables.

But you need to import bootstrap styles in this mystyle.scss too.After that, you need the following line to import bootstrap styles

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

> Note: Make sure that you import this in the last line of your .scss file.

After importing the bootstrap style, you need to edit the nuxt.config.js

```
export default {

 css: [ { src: '~/assets/bootstrap/mystyle.scss', lang: 'sass'} 
  ],
  
 }
```

This will not only compile the overridden bootstrap styles but also add the bootstrap style in the whole nuxt project.

#### Adding the Javascript Part of Bootstrap

First, download bootstrap. You will get a css and a js folder on that downloaded folder. There are many files under those two folders.
We just need one file from js folder. The name of that file is **bootstrap.bundle.min.js**. Copy that 'bootstrap.bundle.min.js' file and paste that file on your nuxt project's **static** folder. Then you need to edit your nuxt.config.js to use it.

```
export default {
      
    script: [
      {
        src: '/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
      }
    ]
  }
```

That's it, enjoy!

You can read about it in detail in my medium article, [click here](https://rasaf-ibrahim.medium.com/way-to-add-bootstrap-5-with-nuxt-js-1f70e983514).

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to centralize your CSS imports (specifically bootstrap from node_modules, in your case) into a single file for Nuxt generating, you could include an at-rule import to your 'assets/main.css' (recommend to update it to '~/assets/main.css') specified in your config.

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

Just a reminder: when you simply run Nuxt in dev mode, the CSS will be injected via JS. When generated, however, Nuxt will create a single, hashed, CSS file as part of the document root directory.

Comment: Where in my code should I put this line? When i paste it to nuxt.config.js or pages/index.vue I got error "Syntax Error: Unexpected token (3:0)" It for symbol '@' If I remove '@' from start of line I got another error "This relative module was not found:"

Comment: Paste it within assets/main.css

Comment: I maked as you tell, but it not worked for me. Details see in question update. Thanks!

Comment: @MikaS, I updated my question and after this post comment. But now I not see my question update. May be moderators remove it?

Comment: @tolyan You tried to edit this answer, rather than your own question. The edit was not approved, which is why you don't see it.

Comment: @tolyan - I typed in the ref to bootstrap dist incorrectly (forgot to include / /bootstrap after node_modules). According to what I saw in your edit, you included a tilde (~) instead of relative lookup (..). Nuxt won't parse the tilde in assets so use the relative link included in the answer and try again.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I put bootstrap.css file in "static" folder, and then register it to the nuxt.config.js as bellow

```
head: {
title: "Nuxt",
meta: [
  { charset: "utf-8" },
  { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
  {
    hid: "description",
    name: "description",
    content: "Nuxt"
  }
],
link: [
  { rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" },
  { rel: "stylesheet", href: "/css/bootstrap.css" } //Register your static asset 
]
```

},

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I add it from CDN as an object entry to `link` array (in **nuxt.config.js**)

```
link: [     
    {rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my setup, and this is for those who like to customize bootstrap default style:

In my `assets/styles/_bootstrap.scss` I have imported required style:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/type";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/images";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/code";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/transitions";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/button-group";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/input-group";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/custom-forms";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/nav";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/navbar";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/card";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/pagination";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/badge";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/jumbotron";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/alert";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/progress";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/media";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/close";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/modal";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/popover";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/carousel";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/utilities";
//@import "~bootstrap/scss/print";
```

Just in case you like to change the default style of bootstrap then I created `assets/styles/_bootstrap-variables.scss`:

There are lots of variable that you can find in `node-modules/bootstrap/scss/variables.scss`, I am just changing a few.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin:400,500,700');

$font-family-cabin: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
$font-family-base:  $font-family-cabin;

$primary:       #b62f20;
$secondary:     #e8e8e9;
$success:       #87b4a6;
$info:          #f0f6fc;
//$warning:       #faeecf;
//$danger:        $red !default;
//$light:         $gray-100 !default;
//$dark:          $gray-800 !default;
```

And import all my other styles and plugins in one file `assets/styles/main.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap-variables"; // this should alway be on top
@import "bootstrap";
@import "my-other-style";
```

And finally, import the stylesheet in `layouts/default.vue`

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    nuxt
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  @import '../assets/styles/main';
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You install bootstrap-vue :

```
yarn add bootstrap-vue
```

Then in the nuxt.config.js file you add a module, and a separate config for importing the icons :

```
modules: ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt'],
 bootstrapVue: {
   icons: true // Install the IconsPlugin (in addition to BootStrapVue plugin
 }
```

And thats it.
For more configuration read the documentation here : https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs
(Read until the middle where it handles nuxt)

Answer (score 0):

I used for Bootstrap v5

nuxt.config.js

```
  css: [
    '~/assets/scss/main.scss',
  ],
  styleResources: {
    scss: [
      '~/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss',
      '~/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss',
      '~/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss',
      '~/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_containers.scss',
      '~/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_grid.scss'
    ]
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
  ],
```

@nuxtjs/style-resources to have mixins, variables, grid available inside components:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/style-resources
example:

```
<style scoped lang="scss">
.header {
  @include make-container();

}
</style>
```

main.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-configuration";
@import "bootstrap-optional";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/helpers";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
@import "custom";
```

_bootstrap-configuration.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-required";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
```

_bootstrap-optional.scss
(I can include only what I want)

```
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tables";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/forms";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/transitions";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/button-group";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/nav";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/navbar";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/card";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/accordion";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/breadcrumb";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/pagination";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/badge";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/alert";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/progress";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/list-group";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/close";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/toasts";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/tooltip";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/popover";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/carousel";
@import "@/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/spinners";
```

_custom.scss
(here I put variables to override Bootstrap and custom css for components)

```
$theme-colors: (
  "red": #cf142b,
  "black": #000,
  "tan": #e0d9c7,
  "blue": #009eba,
  "blue-light": #d6e3e6,
  "blue-dark": #006985,
  "red-dark": #7d212b,
);

@import
'mixins/mixins';

@import
'_base/colors',
'_base/typography',
'_base/headings';

@import
  'components/_page-header',
  'components/text-editor',
  'components/content-with-side-image',
  'components/featured-artists',
  'components/video-player',
  'components/audio-player',
  'components/call-to-action',
  'components/divider',
  'components/tabs',
  'components/image-gallery',
  'components/logos',
  'components/button',
  'components/page-submenu',
  'components/page-submenu-target';
```

I got idea from
https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/